# Wordpress publish_post fires too often

Tags: wordpress, plugins, publish, slug

I am writing a plugin that simply sends subscribers emails when new post is published(so it shouldn't send any emails when it's on pending, updating, or draft, etc)

In the plugin definition I have:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'setup_plugin_actions');

function setup_plugin_actions(){
  if(has_action('new_to_publish')){
    $simple_email_subscriber = new email_subscriber();

    add_action('new_to_publish', $simple_email_subscriber->email_subscribers());
  }
}

And in my email_subscribers method I have:

class email_subscriber(){
  function email_subscribers(){
    //get post information
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;

    if(wp_is_post_revision($post->ID) || wp_is_post_autosave($post->ID)) return;

    //email code
    ......
  }
}
```

A very simple code that just trying to add an action listener to the **publish_post** method.

However, since publish_post does fire so often, I was getting 8 emails whenever I made an update, new publish, or even if I just stay on the wordpress page and it does auto updates.

I was trying to find some callback that only happens when a new post is truly made: **new_to_post**

Doesn't work at all.

Can someone help me?

Cheers
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting so many emails is because you are not adding the action properly, explained below. As it stands now, you are actually calling your function to send the emails lots of times and hooking the result of the function to the action (which doesn't really do anything), instead of hooking the function to the action.

Your `add_action` has a couple of issues - you are adding your method to the transition `new_to_publish` action (which fires only when a post status is "new" and changes to "publish") and not `publish_post` which will catch posts that are published from any status, and the method you are passing is invalid - the argument is a string for a function or array if it is a method on an object with the first element being the object and the second being the function. It should look like:

```
add_action('publish_post', array($simple_email_subscriber, 'email_subscribers') );
```

Your function is also not taking the `$post_id` as an argument, so it will never know what post to load. Your definition should be:

```
function email_subscribers($post_id){ /* your code */ }
```

You are also calling `$post = get_post( $post_id );` twice in your function which isn't necessary, but if you want to make sure that this function only runs when a post's status is `publish` no matter how it is called, add:

```
$post = get_post( $post_id );
if ($post->post_status != "publish") return;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, they all making sense, however, after modification, it still sends a email every post update, because once the post is published, it will always on the status of publish? I only want it send email the first time it publishes

Comment: I would recommend setting a post meta to indicate if the email has been sent or not, and check that at the top of our function. if the meta is true, return the method.

Comment: Setting a meta for it is the solution ! although im sure wordpress can do better than that !

Comment: @phil88530 There are some other options, but setting a meta works best im my opinion. Say the email doesn't send for some reason, but the function is hooked to an action that fires once and only once... how do you resend? With the meta route you can just resave the post.